Put the given numbers in increasing order.
Question
Let
$$
\begin{aligned}
& V_1=\frac{7^2+8^2+15^2+23^2}{4}-\left(\frac{7+8+15+23}{4}\right)^2, \\
& V_2=\frac{6^2+8^2+15^2+24^2}{4}-\left(\frac{6+8+15+24}{4}\right)^2, \\
& V_3=\frac{5^2+8^2+15^2+25^2}{4}-\left(\frac{5+8+15+25}{4}\right)^2 .
\end{aligned}
$$
Then
(A) $V_3<V_2<V_1$
(B) $V_3<V_1<V_2$
(C) $V_1<V_2<V_3$
(D) $V_2<V_3<V_1$.
Attempt
All I can see is since $x^{2}$ is a concave up function each of the following numbers above are greater than (0r equal to?) $0$. But I don't have any clue on comparing their magnitudes with each other.

Hint: For a random variable $X$, we know that $\operatorname{Var}(X) = \operatorname{E}(X^2) - \operatorname{E}(X)^2$.

How to apply that here. I know the result for a fact.

Well, at a glance it's clear that values spread out from the first to the second to the third list of values and variance is a measure of this spread!
